# Splitting an Int to 3 bytes and back in C

Tags: c, int

I have the following code to split an int into 3 bytes and then back:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main()
{
    int a = 626;
    uint8_t msb = (a >> 16) & 0xff;
    uint8_t msb1 = (a >> 8) & 0xff;
    uint8_t lsb = a & 0xff;

    printf("MSB: %u, MSB1: %u, LSB: %u\n", msb, msb1, lsb);

    uint8_t h1 = msb << 16;
    uint8_t h2 = msb1 << 8;
    uint8_t h3 = lsb & 0xff;

    int b = h1 | h2 | h3;

    printf("Final: %d\n", b);

    return 0;
}
```

When I run this code the output is as follows:
MSB: 0, MSB1: 2, LSB: 114
Final: 114

I should get Final as 626 but I get 114. It would be great if someone could help out. Thanks

Comment: `uint8_t h1 = msb << 16;` - have you noticed the resulting type?

Comment: `int` being _three_ bytes wide is unusual, are you sure it shouldn't be four?

Comment: `int` is not guaranteed to have more than 16 bits. If you want a specific width, use fixed width types! Also shifting signed integers is problematic. Depending on value, shift count and direction it is implementation defined or even undefined behaviour. Use unsigned types!

Comment: @zwol: OP confuses byte and "8 bits". He seems to want 8 bits. And there are indeed CPUs with 24 bit integers.

Comment: @Olaf Yes, there are, but they are unusual and I doubt OP would be asking a question like this if they were working on one of them.

Comment: @zwol: I'm not sure. The question is typical for a beginner in the job first time confronted with such an architecture. Many C courses at universities are not worth the time. Problem is the students are often not even aware they are not really prepared for the job. ("You need to have a certain degree of understanding of the matter to understand you don't understand a problem")

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A possible solution is

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main(void)
{
    int a = 626;
    uint8_t msb = (a >> 16) & 0xff;
    uint8_t msb1 = (a >> 8) & 0xff;
    uint8_t lsb = a & 0xff;

    printf("MSB: %u, MSB1: %u, LSB: %u\n", msb, msb1, lsb);

    uint32_t b = msb;
    b = (b<<8) | msb1;
    b = (b<<8) | lsb;

    printf("Final: %d\n", b);

    return 0;
}
```

As you can see:

1. I changed the type of b: left shift signed values can be UB.

> 6.5.7/4 [...]  If E1 has a signed type and nonnegative value, and E1×2<sup>E2</sup> is representable in the result type, then that is the resulting value; otherwise, the behavior is undefined.

2. What you did it was right shift a char (`8 bits`) right by `8` or `16`, which means you lost all your bits. So as you can see you can, first of all, assign first value to a larger variable (unsigned int) and after that shift it.

Answer (score 0):

Try using something bigger than `uint8_t`
e.g. u`int32_t`

Answer (score 0):

First make sure you aren't mixing signed and unsigned integers. Then I will assume the input integer is an unsigned 32.

My solution is the following :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main()
{
    uint32_t a = 626;
    uint8_t bytes[4];

    bytes[0] = a & 0xff; //contains Lsb
    bytes[1] = (a >> 8) & 0xff;
    bytes[2] = (a >> 16) & 0xff;
    bytes[3] = (a >> 24) & 0xff; //contains msb

    printf("Bytes: %u, %u, %u, %u\n", bytes[0], bytes[1], bytes[2], bytes[3]);

    uint32_t b = (bytes[3] << 24) | (bytes[2] << 16) | (bytes[1] << 8) | bytes[0];

    printf("Final: %u\n", b);

    return 0;
}
```

Where as Mischa said. You need to work the result back in something larger than 8 bits. Otherwise you are loosing the bits when shifting more than 8 bits.

Comment: If using all recommended warnigs, you will get a truncation warning. Add a cast where necessary (I'll leave to you or OP figuring out which are:).

Comment: Your solution has the same problem as OP. When you `bytes[3] << 24`, you lost the bits. Check @LPs answer for details.